# INNER JOIN entre dois SELECT

Tags: select, join

Consigo fazer o `INNER JOIN` entre dois `SELECT` seguindo a estrutura abaixo?  Pois a ideia é acrescentar mais alguns `SELECT`

```
/* Select 1 */

        SELECT

        AVG (UR1_Demanda) as UR1_DemandaAVG,

        DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

        FROM MTC_CF_MM 

        WHERE UR1_Demanda <> 0

        GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

        ORDER BY id

/* Select 2 */

        SELECT

        AVG (UR2_Demanda) as UR2_DemandaAVG,

        DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

        FROM MTC_CF_MM 

        WHERE UR2_Demanda <> 0

        GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

        ORDER BY id

 /* JOIN  */

        SELECT *

        FROM Select1 as A 

        INNER JOIN Select2 as B ON A.id = B.id
```

Estou com dúvida de como referenciar/mencionar os `SELECT` dentro da sintaxe do `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível fazer `JOIN` com uma `SELECT`, nesse caso cada `SELECT` será uma *subquery*.

Para isso, inclua o `SELECT` entre parênteses e dê a ele um *alias* (nome), algo assim:

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM (SELECT Avg (ur1_demanda)                AS UR1_DemandaAVG,
               Datepart(dayofyear, e3timestamp) AS id
        FROM   mtc_cf_mm
        WHERE  ur1_demanda <> 0
        GROUP  BY Datepart(dayofyear, e3timestamp)
        ORDER  BY id) AS A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Avg (ur2_demanda)                AS UR2_DemandaAVG,
                     Datepart(dayofyear, e3timestamp) AS id
                FROM   mtc_cf_mm
                WHERE  ur2_demanda <> 0
                GROUP  BY Datepart(dayofyear, e3timestamp)
                ORDER  BY id) AS B ON A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

A abordagem vai depender do banco que você está usando, mas em geral a ideia é pensar em relações.

Quando dizemos que um banco é relacional dizemos que ele trabalha com relações, e ao contrário do que algumas pessoas pensam relações não são relacionamentos entre tabelas.

Suponha que você tenha uma tabela x como abaixo:

```
Coluna - Tipo
id - number
nome - varchar
sobrenome - varchar
email - varchar
```

Neste caso algo como:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT nome, email FROM x
```

é uma relação.

Munido desta informação podemos pensar agora em como trabalhar relações.

Alguns bancos tem a figura do WITH, que permite criar relações para então usar em consultas.

- MySQL -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html
- Oracle ->
  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCGAAJ
- PostgreSQL -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Munido destas duas informações nós podemos fazer algo assim:

```sql
WITH relacao_um as (

        SELECT

        AVG (UR1_Demanda) as UR1_DemandaAVG,

        DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

        FROM MTC_CF_MM 

        WHERE UR1_Demanda <> 0

        GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

        ORDER BY id

), relacao_dois as (

        SELECT

        AVG (UR2_Demanda) as UR2_DemandaAVG,

        DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

        FROM MTC_CF_MM 

        WHERE UR2_Demanda <> 0

        GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

        ORDER BY id

)

        SELECT *

        FROM relacao_um 

        INNER JOIN relacao_2 ON relacao_um.id = relacao_2.id
```

**Outra abordagem que é possível em alguns bancos (nem todos vão aceitar):** é incluir a relação direto no JOIN:

```sql
SELECT *

FROM (
  SELECT

  AVG (UR1_Demanda) as UR1_DemandaAVG,

  DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

  FROM MTC_CF_MM 

  WHERE UR1_Demanda <> 0

  GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

  ORDER BY id

) as A 

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT

  AVG (UR2_Demanda) as UR2_DemandaAVG,

  DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

  FROM MTC_CF_MM 

  WHERE UR2_Demanda <> 0

  GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

  ORDER BY id
) as B ON A.id = B.id
```

Espero ter ajudado, ter em mente que bancos relacionais trabalham com relações facilita muito a vida.

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem que você pode utilizar é usar o operador [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
/* Select 1 */
    (SELECT

    AVG (UR1_Demanda) as UR1_DemandaAVG,

    DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

    FROM MTC_CF_MM 

    WHERE UR1_Demanda <> 0

    GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

    ORDER BY id)
    
    UNION
    
    /* Select 2 */

    (SELECT

    AVG (UR2_Demanda) as UR2_DemandaAVG,

    DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp) as id

    FROM MTC_CF_MM 

    WHERE UR2_Demanda <> 0

    GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear, E3TimeStamp)

    ORDER BY id)
```

Comment: e como esse union faz o join, que é a dúvida da pergunta? além disso, é importante adicionar uma nota que isso só funciona se ambos os selects tiverem o mesmo numero de campos/tipos